# select tied to session object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I'm using rails' `select` helper on my page, dynamically populated with `Categories` on a page showing news articles. Changing the select should refresh the page and show news articles for the selected category. I'm storing the category id in the session. How do I make my `select` show persist the correct selected value? Currently trying this but it doesn't work:

```
  <%= select "session", "news_category_id", 
             @categories.collect {|c| [ c.name, c.id ]}, 
             {:prompt => "Filter news by company"}
  %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the value of news_category_id was a string...`/facepalm`